# Retrieving returned value from fetch inside render()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having a little trouble, I have JSON data which is being fetched, and then the data is rendered. However within the render I need to perform another fetch as the data I'm trying to render relies on the first JSON.

You can see I'm trying grab the returned value, but it comes as undefined.

So the fetch looks like this:

```
getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json) {
    fetch(thumbnail_json)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        return responseData.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url;
      })
      .done();
  }
```

and the renderPost() is:

```
renderPosts() {
    contents = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
      let postDate = Moment(post.date).format('LLL');

      if ( post._links['wp:featuredmedia'] ) {
        console.log('has featured image');
        let thumbnail_json = post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href;
        this.getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json);
        console.log(this.getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json)); // <----- UNDEFINED?
      } else {
        console.log('no featured image');
      }

      return (
        <View key={post.id} style={ postStyles.postContainer }>
          <Text style={postStyles.postTitle}>
            {post.title.rendered}
          </Text>
          <Text style={postStyles.postDate}>
            {postDate}
          </Text>
          <View style={ postStyles.excerptContainer }>
            <HTMLView stylesheet={htmlStyles}
              value={post.excerpt.rendered}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={baseStyles.container}>
          {contents}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return anything currently, add a return in front of your fetch:

```
getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json) {
  return fetch(thumbnail_json)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    return responseData.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url;
  })
  .done();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function in `getFeaturedImage` as an argument and call that on `success`

```
mycallback(result) {
    //do what you want with result
}
getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json, callback) {
    fetch(thumbnail_json)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        callback(responseData.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url);
      })
      .done();
  }

renderPosts() {
    contents = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
      let postDate = Moment(post.date).format('LLL');

      if ( post._links['wp:featuredmedia'] ) {
        console.log('has featured image');
        let thumbnail_json = post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href;
        this.getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json, this.mycallback);
        console.log(this.getFeaturedImage(thumbnail_json)); // <----- UNDEFINED?
      } else {
        console.log('no featured image');
      }

      return (
        <View key={post.id} style={ postStyles.postContainer }>
          <Text style={postStyles.postTitle}>
            {post.title.rendered}
          </Text>
          <Text style={postStyles.postDate}>
            {postDate}
          </Text>
          <View style={ postStyles.excerptContainer }>
            <HTMLView stylesheet={htmlStyles}
              value={post.excerpt.rendered}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={baseStyles.container}>
          {contents}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It appears, i have found another solution, the api im using actually has another json which outputs all the data, meaning i can just make the single request.